# How do I give a sphere an angle of inclination in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create the moon - earth system in Three JS. I want the moon sphere to be on a tilt of 6.68 degrees and the earth sphere to be on a tilt of 23.5. I am very new to Three JS and I didn't find anything in the docs related to axis or tilt, could anyone point out how I could achieve this?

I have tried to use applyMatrix4 but I'm not succeeding

```
// Moon

const moonTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('moon.jpg')
const normalTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('normal.jpg')

const moon = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(3,32,32),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: moonTexture,
    normalMap: normalTexture
  })
)
moon.position.x = -10
moon.position.y = 5
moon.position.z = -15
scene.add(moon)
```

EDIT:

Using the following seems to work:

```
new THREE.SphereGeometry(3,32,32).applyMatrix4( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, - 1 ).normalize(), 6.68 ) ),
```

However I'm not entirely sure how to properly pick a vector to use with the makeRotationAxis method

Comment: I think what you are looking for is "rotation", you can rotate the object in any axis in radians. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.rotation

Comment: What I want to do is 'spawn' the objects on an inclination instead of upright, and then apply a y-axis rotation

Comment: instead, you spawn the object upright, rotate it about either x or z so that it's correctly inclined, and then you can animate the rotation about the y axis.

Comment: https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/RwyzrVj?editors=0010 lines 103, 104 about rotation order and inclination

Comment: @prisoner849 that looks really cool, the color gradient and rotations look sick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rotate the y-axis of your "moon" to 6.68 degrees. Since `three.js` uses radians, you can convert:

```txt
6.68deg => 0.12rad (approx)
```

Now we apply that to your object:

```js
moon.rotation.[axisOfRotation] = 0.12; //Rotations in radians by default
```

Comment: I'll pick this is as the correct answer to close the question, another way I got it to work is rotating it along the z axis just one once using ```useEffect```, as I'm using react